# search multiple rows with the same values sql

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table in my database which has the following structure:

```
ID | Date | Ball1 | Ball2 | Ball3 | Ball4 | Ball5 | Ball6 | Ball7 | BonusBall
```

All the Ball rows are just integers.

What I want to do now is to write a select query that selects all the rows that have multiple of the same values in it.

For instance all the rows that contain 1 and 12.

I tried the following query, but that doesn't quite give my what I want:

```
SELECT * FROM number 
WHERE ball1 OR ball2 OR ball3 OR ball4 OR ball5 OR ball6 OR bonusball IN (1,12);
```

Am I on the right track? Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry everyone I should actually explain this a little better I don't want any rows that contain either 1 or 12 but just the ones that contain both. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution was already pretty good, but if you want to check it for each field, I believe you have to write it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE (ball1 = 1 OR ball2 = 1 OR ball3  = 1  
OR ball4  = 1 OR ball5 = 1 OR ball6  = 1 OR bonusball = 1)
AND (ball1 = 12 OR ball2 = 12 OR ball3 = 12  
OR ball4 = 12 OR ball5 = 12 OR ball6 = 12 OR bonusball = 12);
```

Although I would not advise running this query in a high traffic environment. A better idea would be to have two tables. One containing 'Lottery' and the other one 'Balls'. Where Balls would have a reference to the lottery table.

You should try to read up on [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Thanks very much! I just needed to get verification that I was doing it correctly. Many thanks Liam

Comment: Actually I should probably explain a little better this does bring up rows that contain 1 and12 for instance however I was it to bring up rows that contain both 1 and 12 only? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've changed my answer to reflect this. This should work. Mark my answer as the solution if it helped you :-)

Answer (score 0):

first of all - you should practice 'normalization'

second a better syntax would be

```
SELECT * 
FROM number 
WHERE ball1 in (1,12) 
OR ball2 in (1,12) 
OR ball3 in (1,12)
```

etc

Comment: Thanks for the advice it is always better practice to use the correct syntax so thanks for this too Randy! Also you were so fast to respond! Thanks!